# Overleaf v1 and v2: How to delete a project in overleaf?

Tags: latex, tex

Thanks to the UI developers of overleaf.

It looks like the DELETE button is hidden deep somewhere in overleaf.

It was very difficult for me to find the delete button, though I checked at all the menu and buttons.

If somebody had had a luck deleting projects in overleaf, I would greatly appreciate the method.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions here are usually more neutral in tone. I suggest removing the 1st, 3rd, and last line of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seem to be two ways:

1. Version 1 (or `V1`) projects can be managed using the [version 1 dashboard](https://www.overleaf.com/dash?prefer-v1-dash=1).
2. Projects created under version 2 have to be *archived* first. Once this is done, click on the Archived Projects menu item where you can "delete [them] forever".

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

To delete a project from overleaf, you have to save it in the archive, than you can delete it permanently from the archive.

Save the project in the archive:

[image]

Delete the project from the archive:

[image]

[image]